# Android Studio Robotium Recorder Plugin Compatibility issue

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

[image: New Robotium Test]

I have Android API Levels 15,19,20,21 and Android Studio 1.0.1.

Robotium Recorder needs API 15 or higher version. [Information about Robotium API support](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Changelog)

I follow that guide from [Robotium's page](http://robotium.com/pages/installation-android-studio) 
and also I tried many things like those (all following steps were tested separately from each other);

- I created emulators that's API level 15 and 19, Than I tried to start Robotium,It did not work.
- I connected my Android phone which is API level 19,that did not work again.
- I started Android Studio with administrator permission everytime.
- I downloaded robotium.jar [here](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started) It did not work.

I tried every method in my mind.

My minimum sdk version and target sdk version is also 19.
But when I clicked "New Robotium Test" button, immediately appears warning text that is **"Please install a compatible Android API level (15 or higher)"**

There is a screenshot about problem. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two Android SDK:s installed in your computer. If you go to settings (on the left side of "New Robotium Test") you can change the SDK to be used by Robotium Recorder.

http://robotium.com/pages/user-guide-android-studio

Comment: I do not think so. I checked twice, I have only "1" SDK and path is correct.