# Robotium recorder - Please install a higher api level 15 or greater

Tags: java, android-studio, robotium, robotium-recorder

It's telling me

> Please install a higher api level 15 or greater

I managed to change my api level to greater than 15 in my gradle and sdk manager but it's still telling me that.

What should I do?

Comment: Have look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908481/robotium-please-install-a-compatible-android-api-level-15-or-higher

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Robotium: Please install a compatible Android API level (15 or higher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908481/robotium-please-install-a-compatible-android-api-level-15-or-higher)

Comment: It says thati should change my support libraries from 25+ to 25.+ in my dependencies. I dont understand??  Actually im connected my mobile device via usb to my computer to perform the testing.  Can you please explain in details to me what should i do since I'm not being able to understand from the link?

Comment: @RamPrakash can you help me or anyone?? Im stuck with this..

Comment: first follow nick answer and follow flink’s answer from the url i shared

Comment: I followed nick's answer and filnik's answer but it did not work....     what should i do next? Please help?

Comment: @RamPrakash  My compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are both 28 and minSdkVersion is 22 and in my Android SDK manager i have already installed the api level 15,22,28,29

Comment: I don't have a way to emulate your config.. Can you if you fall under this sceanrio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511881/android-studio-robotium-recorder-plugin-compatibility-issue

Comment: I only have 1 sdk i ckecked..but it doesnt work :/